# I'm trying to create a simple express application but it seems not to be working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a simple express application but while it is running in console. when i hit localhost:3000 in my browser I get network errors. I don't seem to know what the problem is.

Here is my code.

```
 var hostname = 'localhost';
 var port = 3000;

 var app = express ();

 app.use (function (req, res, next) {
     console.log (req.headers);

     res.writeHead (200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     res.end ( '<html><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>');
 });


 // listing for request at port: 7000 no http.createServer needed

 app.listen (console.log (
  `Success server running at http://${hostname}: ${port}`
 ));
```

However when I created a similar app in pure node it worked fine.

Here is my code:

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var path = require ('path');
 var http = require ('http');

 var hostname = 'localhost';
 var port = 3000;

 var server = http.createServer (function (req, res) {
   console.log ('request for ' + req.url + ' using ' + req.method + ' method');


    // checking if the request method is Get
    if (req.method == 'GET') {

        var fileUrl;
        // checking for the request url if it is the home page or not and storing the correct request url in fileUrl variable
            if (req.url == '/') fileUrl = '/index.html';
                 else fileUrl = req.url;
            var filePath = path.resolve ('./public'+fileUrl);
            var fileExt = path.extname (filePath);

            if (fileExt == '.html' && req.url !== '/favicon.ico') {
                fs.exists (filePath, function (exists) {
                   if (!exists) {
                    res.writeHead (404, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
                    res.end ('<h1> The file </h1>' + fileUrl + '<h1>is not found. Make sure your browser input is correct and try again!</h1>');
                    console.log('hello no favicon found');
                    return;
                   }
                });
            }

        res.writeHead (200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        fs.createReadStream (filePath).pipe(res);  
    } else {
        res.writeHead (404, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.end ('<h1> The file' + fileUrl + 'not an html file');
        console.log (fileUrl);
    }
 });


 server.listen (port, hostname, function (){
     console.log (`server started ${hostname}:${port}. Helloooooo`);
 });
```

Thanks for your review and response!

Comment: You get *errors*? -> Show them! And your call to `app.listen` makes no sense at all, you may do `app.listen(port, err => console.log(err))`

Comment: I checked your code. u missed requiring express in first part of ur code other than that everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the line.

```
var express = require('express')
```

add this line on the top of your code and try and don't forget to add NPM module express

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code.

You should install `express` in your project. You can use the below command to do so.

```
npm install express --save
```

And then use the below code on top.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Then, you must provide a port parameter in the `listen` call.

```
app.listen(3000);
```

Other APIs and options can be found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the app generator from express, fast and easy, you'll get the basic working structure.

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Express application generator
Use the application generator tool, express-generator, to quickly create an application skeleton.
The express-generator package installs the express command-line tool. Use the following command to do so:

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
```

Display the command options with the -h option:

```
   $ express -h

Usage: express [options] [dir]
Options:
-h, --help          output usage information
        --version       output the version number
    -e, --ejs           add ejs engine support
        --hbs           add handlebars engine support
        --pug           add pug engine support
    -H, --hogan         add hogan.js engine support
    -v, --view <engine> add view <engine> support (ejs|hbs|hjs|jade|pug|twig|vash) (defaults to jade)
    -c, --css <engine>  add stylesheet <engine> support (less|stylus|compass|sass) (defaults to plain css)
        --git           add .gitignore
    -f, --force         force on non-empty directory
```

For example, the following creates an Express app named myapp. The app will be created in a folder named myapp in the current working directory and the view engine will be set to Pug:

```
$ express --view=pug myapp

create : myapp
   create : myapp/package.json
   create : myapp/app.js
   create : myapp/public
   create : myapp/public/javascripts
   create : myapp/public/images
   create : myapp/routes
   create : myapp/routes/index.js
   create : myapp/routes/users.js
   create : myapp/public/stylesheets
   create : myapp/public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : myapp/views
   create : myapp/views/index.pug
   create : myapp/views/layout.pug
   create : myapp/views/error.pug
   create : myapp/bin
   create : myapp/bin/www
```

Then install dependencies:

```
$ cd myapp
$ npm install
```

On MacOS or Linux, run the app with this command:

```
$ DEBUG=myapp:* npm start
```

On Windows, use this command:

```
> set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start
```

Then load http://localhost:3000/ in your browser to access the app.
The generated app has the following directory structure:

```
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.pug
    ├── index.pug
    └── layout.pug
7 directories, 9 files
The app structure created by the generator is just one of many ways to structure Express apps. Feel free to use this structure or modify it to best suit your needs.
```